# How to use F1 score as an evaluation metric for XGBoost validation?

Tags: python, xgboost, grid-search

I'm trying to validate a model using GridSearchCV and XGBoost. I want my evaluation metric to be F1 score. I've seen many people use `scoring='f1'` and `eval_metric=f1_score` and other variations. I'm confused on a couple of points. Why are some people using `scoring=` and others using `eval_metric=`?

In the [XGBoost documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html), there's no F1 score evaluation metric (which seems strange, btw, considering some of the others they do have). But I see lots of advice online to "just use XGBoost's built-in F1 score evaluator." Where??

No matter what I put here, my code throws an error on the `eval_metric` line.

Here is my code:

```
params = {
    'max_depth': range(2,10,2),
    'learning_rate': np.linspace(.1, .6, 6),
    'min_child_weight': range(1,10,2),
}

grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1,
                              n_estimators=500,
                              random_state=0),
    param_grid = params,
)

eval_set = [(X_tr, y_tr),
            (X_val, y_val)]

grid.fit(X_tr, y_tr,
         eval_set=eval_set,
         eval_metric='f1',  # <------What do I put here to make this evaluate based on f1 score???
         early_stopping_rounds=25,
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
result = cross_val_score(
    estimator = your_xgboost_model,
    X = X_dataframe, 
    y = Y_dataframe, 
    scoring = 'f1',
    cv = 10
)
```